# UITextViews not cleared when selected in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I'm implementing a UITableView with text-views as the content view of my cells.

The data that the user enters is saved in a settings dictionary when the user hits the return key:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == _textFieldOne){
        [settingsDictionary setObject: _textFieldOne.text forKey:@"EntryOneText"];
        [settingsDictionary stringValueForKey:@"textFieldOneValue"];
        [self postNotificationSettingsUpdate:settingsDictionary];
        didTestPostNotificationSettings = YES;
}
```

These saved values should be displayed in the text-field when the user returns back to the screen, which I've done using the code below:

```
    //Set the value in the text fields from the settings dictionary
    NSString *textFieldOneText = [self.settingsDictionary       stringValueForKey:@"RedZoneCarsPerManHrMin"];

    _textFieldOne.text = textFieldOneValue;
```

So far, everything seems to work as expected: text input is saved, and shown in the text-field when the user returns to screen. However, if the *row* of the TableView that holds the text-field is select (not the text-field *itself*), the text-field displays the behavior shown below:

[image]

It appears as if the text-field is showing both the newly inputted entry, as well as the entry that was last saved.

**EDIT** I'ved added more of my cellForRowAtIndexPath method below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForSubscribedRedZoneAlertRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RedZoneAlertCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.922 green:0.937 blue:0.949 alpha:1];

    UISwitch *cellSwitch = nil;

    NSNumber *position = enabledRedZoneAlertRows[indexPath.row];


switch (position.integerValue) {
    case CarPerManHourRow: {
        cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Label", @"Label Row");
        cellSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        cellSwitch.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:SwitchKey];
        cellSwitch.tag = SwitchTag;
        [cellSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        cell.accessoryView = cellSwitch;

        if ([[self.settingsDictionary valueForKey:@"RedZoneCarsPerManHrOnOff"]isEqual: @"1"]){
            [cellSwitch setOn:YES];
        }
        break;
    }
    case TextFieldRow: {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ConfigCell";
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:_textFieldOne];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:_textFieldTwo];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:_spacingLabel];
        }

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.922 green:0.937 blue:0.949 alpha:1];

        _textFieldOne = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 0, 50, 30)];
        _textFieldTwo = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 50, 30)];

        _textFieldOne.delegate = self;
        _textFieldTwo.delegate = self;

        _textFieldOne.placeholder = @"Auto";
        _textFieldTwo.placeholder = @"Auto";
        [_textFieldOne setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_textFieldTwo setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

        //Set the value in the text fields from the settings dictionary
       NSString *textFieldOneText = [self.settingsDictionary stringValueForKey:@"RedZoneCarsPerManHrMin"];
       NSString *textFieldTwoText = [self.settingsDictionary stringValueForKey:@"RedZoneCarsPerManHrMax"];

        NSString *carsPerManHrMax = [self.settingsDictionary stringValueForKey:@"RedZoneCarsPerManHrMax"];
        NSString *carsPerManHrMax = [self.settingsDictionary stringValueForKey:@"RedZoneCarsPerManHrMax"];

        _textFieldOne.text = textFieldOneValue;
        _textFieldTwo.text = textFieldTwoValue

        _textFieldOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _textFieldTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _textFieldOne.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _textFieldTwo.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [_textFieldOne.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
        [_textFieldTwo.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];

        [_textFieldOne setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
        [_textFieldTwo setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];

        _textFieldOne.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        _textFieldTwo.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

        _spacingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0, 35, 30)];
        _spacingLabel.text = @"–";
        _spacingLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.658 green:0.658 blue:0.658 alpha:1];
        [_spacingLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        _spacingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        //[cell.contentView addSubview:_textFieldOne];
        //[cell.contentView addSubview:_textFieldTwo];
        //[cell.contentView addSubview:_spacingLabel];

        break;
    }
   return cell;
}
```

**EDIT TWO** 
Below is my attempt at fixing my issue based on jherran's answer. However, I am still experiencing the same problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForSubscribedRedZoneAlertRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RedZoneAlertCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.922 green:0.937 blue:0.949 alpha:1];

    UISwitch *cellSwitch = nil;

    NSNumber *position = enabledRedZoneAlertRows[indexPath.row];

    switch (position.integerValue) {
        case CarPerManHourRow: {
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Label", @"Label Row");
            cellSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
            cellSwitch.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:SWSettingCarsPerManHour];
            cellSwitch.tag = SaveCarsPerManHourTag;
            [cellSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            cell.accessoryView = cellSwitch;

            if ([[self.settingsDictionary valueForKey:@"RedZoneCarsPerManHrOnOff"]isEqual: @"1"]){
                [cellSwitch setOn:YES];
            }
            break;
        }
        case CarsPerManHourConfigRow: {

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ConfigCell";
            cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.922 green:0.937 blue:0.949 alpha:1];

                _carsPerManHourMinTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 0, 50, 30)];
                _carsPerManHourMaxTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 50, 30)];

                _textFieldOne.delegate = self;
                _textFieldTwo.delegate = self;

                _textFieldOne.placeholder = @"Auto";
                _textFieldTwo.placeholder = @"Auto";
                [_textFieldOne setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
                [_textFieldTwo setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];




                _textFieldOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                _textFieldTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                _textFieldOne.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                _textFieldTwo.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];


                [_textFieldOne.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
                [_textFieldTwo.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];

                [_textFieldOne setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
                [_carsPerManHourMaxTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];

                _textFieldOne.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
                _textFieldTwo.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

                _spacingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0, 35, 30)];
                _spacingLabel.text = @"–";
                _spacingLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.658 green:0.658 blue:0.658 alpha:1];
                [_spacingLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
                _spacingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                NSLog(@"%@", _textFieldOne.text);
                NSLog(@"%@",_carsPerManHourMaxTextField.text);

                [cell.contentView addSubview: _textFieldOne];
                [cell.contentView addSubview: _textFieldTwo];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:_spacingLabel];

                cell.tag = 1;
            }

            else {
                _textFieldOne = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
                _textFieldTwo = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
                _spacingLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
            }

            NSString * _textFieldOne = [self.settingsDictionary stringValueForKey:@"RedZoneCarsPerManHrMin"];
            NSString *carsPerManHrMax = [self.settingsDictionary stringValueForKey:@"RedZoneCarsPerManHrMax"];

            _textFieldOne.text = carsPerManHrMin;
            _textFieldTwo.text = carsPerManHrMax;
```

How do I modify my code so that this behavior does not occur?

Comment: Please show us the whole cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod.

Comment: Hi @EarlGrey, I've added most of my cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod in my edit. I wasn't able to add the entire method, as it's quite long (their are man y cells in this particular section of the table-view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, as cells are reused, you are probably not loading the cell property.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /*
     *   This is an important bit, it asks the table view if it has any available cells
     *   already created which it is not using (if they are offscreen), so that it can
     *   reuse them (saving the time of alloc/init/load from xib a new cell ).
     *   The identifier is there to differentiate between different types of cells
     *   (you can display different types of cells in the same table view)
     */

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    /*
     *   If the cell is nil it means no cell was available for reuse and that we should
     *   create a new one.
     */
    UILabel *label;
    if (cell == nil) {

        /* 
         *   Actually create a new cell (with an identifier so that it can be dequeued). 
         */

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
        cell.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    } else {

        label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    }

    /*
     *   Now that we have a cell we can configure it to display the data corresponding to
     *   this row/section
     */

     label.text = @"whatever";
}
```

EDIT: When your cell exits and it's reused, you are adding a view (`[cell.contentView addSubview:_textFieldOne]`) each time the cell is reused.

Comment: Ahh, I'm glad I saw your edit, that makes sense! So in other words, I need to only add my textField to a cell's subview once, correct? How would I implement that?

Comment: You must add it when `cell == nil`. There you init the cell and all it's subviews. That's the way.

Comment: see my comprehensive solution in my answer.

Comment: @jherran I tried that suggestion, but am still getting the same behavior.

Comment: Could you please update your code with that changes?

Comment: @jherran Yup! Just did :)

Comment: Check my answer, I update my example with a `UILabel`.

Comment: Could we discuss this in chat? I'm close, but still (apparently) doing something wrong..

Comment: HI @jherran, I edited my question to reflect my attempt at solving my problem based on your answer. Would you mind taking a look once more? Thank you!

Comment: @narner just see. You have one thing bad. The tag is for each textfield: `_textFieldOne.tag = 1`, `_textFieldTwo.tag = 2`, ... This way your have a reference to it when the cell will be reused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72156/discussion-between-narner-and-jherran).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is as I suspected. Every time the cell is taken out out the reuse queue, you create a new instance of textfield and add it to the content view. So basically the content view is piling up with new textfields. 
What you should do is

1) to have a custom cell and make the cell the sole class responsible for its internals

2) expose only a configuration method to pass a raw text to cell

3) call that configuration method when thr cell is reused.

4) keep a reference to the textfield inside the custom cell to be able to update the text value any time incl. when it is recycled in cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: That makes far as what is wrong. I'm afraid I don't fully understand your solution though; would you mind explaining a bit more? My apologies!

Comment: What specifically should be in more detail?